# C++ Convert angles to coordinates

Tags: c++, algorithm, matlab, formula

I'm currently trying to convert 2 angles into x, y, z, using a formula from Matlab from Mathworks, Sph2Cart

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sph2cart.html

#### Algorithm:

```
x = r .* cos(elevation) .* cos(azimuth)
y = r .* cos(elevation) .* sin(azimuth)
z = r .* sin(elevation)
```

#### In C++

```
clax = 1 * cos((Altitude/360)*(2*XM_PI)) * cos((Azimuth/360)*(2*XM_PI));
clay = 1 * sin((Altitude/360)*(2*XM_PI));
claz = 1 * cos((Altitude/360)*(2*XM_PI)) * sin((Azimuth/360)*(2*XM_PI));
```

But no matter what Altitude and Azimuth is, clax, clay and claz is either 0 or 1.

I'm sure that i made a mistake, and i will laugh after this how stupid i was. But really, i have no idea why this doesn't work, why the values only give 1 or 0 for each of them...

Comment: Not at a workstation to verify, but from first glance I see two things to check out: 1) You're doing integer math in the trig calls...you need to be doing floating point math (i.e. Altitude should be a `double` and you divide by 360.)  and 2) make sure your arguments to trig functions are in radians, not degrees

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all likelihood, you declared `clax` as some integer type (e.g. `int`, `long`, ...). Otherwise, `Altitude` or `Azimuth` might be declared as integer types. In that case you would always wind up with multiples of `2*pi` in the arguments to the trigonometric functions.

Comment: @user1492812: What type do `Altitude` and `Azimuth` have?

Comment: Alright, they were declared as integers, changed them to double, the value changes between 0 to 1 now(actually between them), sorry for that mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The problem are most likely the divisions `Altitude/360` and `Azimuth/360`, when `Altitude` and `Azimuth` are integers. This will perform an integer division and you loose the fractions. As an illustrative example, try this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    int angle = 90;
    std::cout << std::sin((angle/360)*(2*M_PI)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::sin((angle/360.0)*(2*M_PI)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::sin((angle/360.0)*(2.0*M_PI)) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs

```
0
1
1
```

Note that the first zero is obviously incorrect.

To fix your code, simply change the integer constants from `360` to double-constants `360.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is helpful, but works for me....

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double XM_PI = 3.14159;
    double Altitude = 32;
    double Azimuth = 24;
    double clax = 1 * cos((Altitude/360)*(2*XM_PI)) * cos((Azimuth/360)*(2*XM_PI));
    double clay = 1 * sin((Altitude/360)*(2*XM_PI));
    double claz = 1 * cos((Altitude/360)*(2*XM_PI)) * sin((Azimuth/360)*(2*XM_PI));
    std::cout << "clax=" << clax << endl;
    std::cout << "clay=" << clay << endl;
    std::cout << "claz=" << claz << endl;
}
```

Answer :

```
clax=0.774731
clay=0.529919
claz=0.344932
```

As others have said, make sure all variables are float/double. Also check what XM_PI is. If it is 0 somehow, that would explain your result.